# Is there any down side to creating objects from reusable parts?

Tags: modeling, texturing

Is there any downside to creating, for example, a structure, say a building from many objects and various textures? Like, create the roof, the walls, a pillar and combine those and export the model into my game engine? Or, for example, a pickaxe, created from different parts, so I can reuse those parts in other models.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about optimizing performance in a third party game engine not Blender.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh No I am asking if it is a good way to create an object , you can ignore the game engine part as I did not ask anything about optimization, I am thinking of reuseability and wanted to know a good way since I am new to modeling in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this will be a problem anywhere. As long as you make sure the objects are properly parented to one another, or even better (at least inside Blender), to an empty, you should be fine. Your game engine will, of course, need to be able to deal with object parenting properly, but if it doesn't... you probably don't want to use it.

@metaphor_set raises a good point in [his answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/51553/3078). You can check [this Unity question where they discuss this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14578/whats-the-best-way-to-reduce-draw-calls.html); however, I still believe that reusing objects will lead to a better workflow. That said, you should really think (aka, benchmark) whether this could become a problem, and, if so, you could, before exporting or, possibly, before applying materials merge the various objects into one, to counter this problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know sir! Thank you!

Comment: @someonewithpc, I reuse objects quite often. I combine the meshes in Blender and create a texture atlas for the objects. It's a bit of a overhead but I'm a bit of a perfectionist and I like to do my models the "clean" way.

Comment: @metaphor_set I am not sure if I am allowed to link youtube but I will do it anyway. You are talking about this technique sir? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spPX3JZOtRc . Sounds really useful and interesting. Will definetly look into that.

Comment: @Mihail: yes, exactly. There are more, somewhat better tutorials about baking to a texture atlas out there but this one covers certainly the basics.

Answer (score 5):

It depends. There's a reason why most modelers try to use as few objects as possible. If you have two objects in a model you have also two materials —  possibly with several textures, every material results in one draw call for DirectX/OpenGL.

If, however, you create one object that contains several submeshes and there is only one material (hint: texture atlas) you'll minimize that unnecessary overhead.